# create view with cursor or loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have managed to create a table from a cursor that inserted rows from similarly named tables in my database. It worked succesfully, but I would like to create a view so that I don't need to update my original query. I may be going down the wrong route using a cursor, but my current query is:

```
use LaganPDM
set nocount on 
declare @table varchar(128)
declare @cmd varchar(500) 
create table SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2 (table_name varchar(128), flods_id numeric(22,0) PRIMARY KEY, lgncc_id numeric(22,0), case_enquiry_id numeric(22,0),amount varchar(4000), costcode varchar(4000), jobcompletedate varchar(4000), jobreleasedate varchar(4000),paymentstatus varchar(4000))
declare tables cursor for
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
   where table_name like '%SPECIAL_UP_C00%'
and left(right(table_name, 24),9) > '101000363'
and not left(right(table_name, 24),9) in('101000487', '101000507', '101000510')
open tables
fetch next from tables into @table
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @cmd = 'select ''' + @table + ''', * from ' + @table 
insert into SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2 exec (@cmd)
  fetch next from tables into @table
END
CLOSE tables 
DEALLOCATE tables
select  * from SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2
```

I've tried to adapt this and create a view, but am having no luck. Any suggestions would be gratefully received, even if this means going down a different route.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this need to be a view?

Comment: A view is a predefined query, you can't use programatically logic like loops, cursors.

Comment: Thx guys. I'm not sure it does necessarily, I was just hoping to produce a query that I could join my existing reports to, so I wouldn't need to update it at any time - each time a new table (with this similar name) is added to the database, my query would automatically pick this up and add it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments, you can't use cursors in a view, only in a stored procedure.

To get the result of the query into a table that is automatically updated each time a new table is added to the database, you can do the following:

First, you already create a permanent table named `SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2` in the database.
You can use this table for your existing reports, so all you need to make sure is that it's updated frequently.
You don't even need to create the table each time the query is executed...just create it once in the database manually and replace the `create table` line at the beginning of your query with this:

```
delete from SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2
```

Plus, you can delete this line at the end:

```
select  * from SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2
```

Now [create a SQL Server Agent job](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sql_server_agent.htm) which executes your query.
You can either just paste your complete query into [the "Command" field](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sql_server_agent_5.htm), or you can save your query as a stored procedure and just execute the stored procedure in the job.
*(I prefer the latter, because that way, the actual code is in the same database as the table - the SQL Server Agent job is saved in the `msdb` system database)*

Schedule the job so that it runs once per day.

That's it!

Now the job will delete and re-populate the `SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2` table once a day, and you can just use that table in all your reports.
If a new table is added to the database, the data from it is in the `SPECIAL_CASE_FORMS_2` table as well on the next day.
*(if you need it earlier than the next day, just schedule the SQL Server Agent job so that it runs several times a day)*

Plus, your reports will run faster this way because they just get the data from the pre-populated table.
Your query above loops through several tables and inserts data into a new table, so doing that again for each report would be slower and cause a bigger load on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think CTE is more suitable than cursor, so  maybe try this

```
use LaganPDM 

Create view as [dbo].[test]
With cteTables as (
select
*
from 
information_schema.tables 
where table_name like '%SPECIAL_UP_C00%' and left(right(table_name, 24),9) > '101000363' and not left(right(table_name, 24),9) in('101000487', '101000507', '101000510'))
Select
* -- because it's a view, you'll have to list all the columns instead of just using select *
From
CteTables
```

Word of warning about CTE though, it can have performance issues if you are going through heaps of records, so just keep that in mind.